# Create folder without using cmd.exe in windows

Tags: windows, cmd, rundll32

EDIT: I have proprietary application which supports only executing windows commands and executables (only from Windows folder) with paramaters and I need to create folder using that but I don't want to see cmd window blink. This app doesn't support any dll imports or code customization.

Is there a way how to create folder in windows without command prompt? When I run

```
cmd /C mkdir "C:\Path\To\Dir"
```

it causes blink of quick showing and hiding cmd window (I want to avoid that).
When I run

```
rundll.exe shell32.dll,SHCreateDirectory "C:\Path\To\Dir"
```

or

```
rundll.exe kernel32.dll,CreateDirectoryA "C:\Path\To\Dir"
```

Command passes just fine, but doestn't create my directory I wanted to create. Would be good to have such command also for creating direcotry with full non existing path.

EDIT2: 
I found a bit nasty, but working workaround for this problem:
I found out that I can create text files using that proprietary app. So first I've created file:
run.vbs
Then I wrote few lines in it:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count >= 1 Then
    ReDim arr(WScript.Arguments.Count-1)
    For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count-1
        Arg = WScript.Arguments(i)
        If InStr(Arg, " ") > 0 Then Arg = """" & Arg & """"
      arr(i) = Arg
    Next
    RunCmd = Join(arr)
    CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run RunCmd, 0, True
End If
```

then run

```
wscript run.vbs cmd /C mkdir "C:\Temp\TmP"
```

And vuola!

Comment: This isn't exactly programming-related...

Comment: From where are you calling this? Is it from an installer?

Comment: It's a specific proprietary application and there is no way to import any dll or create custom code. Only thing it supports is to execute command with parameters.

Comment: It sounds like you are bound to what that application allows you to run. I'm still confused to what the requirements are. If your question is "how to make a folder without command line", and you can't write code, then what would your options be?

Comment: If you know some programming language, why not write a small program to take in some argument and then create a directory?

Comment: I'm guessing you can't run the command `mkdir "somepath"` in the program, without having to call `cmd /C`

Comment: That proprietary application just call [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) in the winapi, right? Or is there another abstraction layer that you are aware of?

Comment: - I can't run mkdir without cmd and yes, it has abstraction layer so no CreateProcess, it's a pretty tricky. So far I've tested cmd /C mkdir ... which works, but the customer doesn't like the blink of cmd window (me neither).

Comment: @BreteP the solution that worked for you is basically my Option 2 but then without starting the cmd again, The FileSystemObject can create folders.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't control how your process is created you are basically at the mersey of the implementers of that code. The winapi [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) does run *.bat and/or *.cmd files but via %ComSpec% /c, which is normally cmd.exe /c. But then, .bat files are no .good here exactly because cmd runs them, which opens a console

Here are a few options that might or might not work in your case:

#### Option 1 (idea from @HarryJohnston)

Use the following powershell command

```
powershell -WindowStyle Minimized -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command mkdir c:\your\path\tocreate > %temp%\scratch.txt
```

#### Option 2

Have the script interpreter run the following file:

```vbs
Dim oFSO
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Create a new folder
oFSO.CreateFolder WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
```

which you start with the following command:

```
wscript mkdirsil.vbs "c:\path\to\create" //NoLogo
```

> //Nologo    Prevent logo display: No banner will be shown at execution time

#### Option 3

Compile the following C# Winforms program that keeps its main window hidden. You need to deploy the executable and I don't know if that is feasible.

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace SilentMkDir
{
    public class Program:Form
    {
        public Program(string dir)
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            this.ControlBox = false;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Text = "MakeDir";
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.Load += (s, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                }
                catch (Exception all)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(all.Message);
                }
                this.Close();
            };
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] path)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Program(path[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

This commandline should produce an*.exe for you, asuming above code is in `mksil.cs`

```
csc mksil.cs /r:System.IO.dll /r:System.Windows.dll
```

Or you could create something similar in C/C++.

#### Option 4 (idea @eryksun)

With Python installed you could do

```
pyw -c "import os; os.mkdir(r'C:\Path\To\Dir')"
```

since pyw.exe is a GUI app

You are basically looking for an exe that is a Windows GUi application instead of a Console application. The following batch command scans the system folder for such executables (put it on one line) but none were found. (notice this needs to run from the commandline, from a script file use %%a instead of %a. [`dumpbin`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) comes with the VC++ compiler

```bash
for %a in (%SystemRoot%\System32\*.exe) do 
      @(dumpbin /headers %a | 
        find "subsystem (Windows GUI)" > nul && 
        echo %~nxa)
```

#### Option Not Possible

Initially I hoped `start` could work but @HarryJohnston pointed out that it is an internal command of cmd and not an exe.

```
start /B /min cmd /c mkdir
```

> Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

but with the /B (no new window) and /MIN (minimized) you might get away with it.

Comment: Problem is that I can use only default windows executables so only one possible way is to start command: cmd /C mkdir ... (it can't start wit start, or just mkdir) Acceptable solution would be to hide this window via some cmd parameter but I didn't fiugure out how.

Comment: I think `powershell.exe` has the necessary functionality.

Comment: Powershell won't accept the `>nul` redirection (generates a "FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as ..." error) but you could redirect to a temporary file or something.  Hopefully not necessary anyway; the application the OP is working with must do something with standard output, and it *might* be something sensible. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, the system creates and shows a console (conhost.exe) for powershell.exe, if it doesn't inherit one. Probably under normal circumstances the window gets minimized too fast to see it, but I expect it'll be visible when the system is busy.

Comment: Rats, so it does.  And wscript.exe doesn't have an option to provide code to run on the command line.  Well, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, maybe you can find something useful in this list of GUI executables: `for %a in (%SystemRoot%\System32\*.exe) do @(dumpbin /headers %a | find "subsystem (Windows GUI)" >
nul && echo %~nxa)`. I don't see anything. With Python installed I'd just use `pyw -c "import os; os.mkdir(r'C:\Path\To\Dir')"`, since pyw.exe is a GUI app. I'm surprised PowerShell doesn't have an equivalent.

Comment: maybe worth a try: are  `bat`files accepted as "default windows executables"?

Comment: @rene, `CreateProcess` runs .bat and .cmd files via `%ComSpec% /c`, which is normally `cmd.exe /c`. But then, .bat files are no good here exactly because cmd runs them, which opens a console.

Comment: The little script to list GUI executables was written for the command prompt; in a batch file it needs to reference the variable as `%%a` instead of `%a`, since it gets doubly parsed. Also, `dumpbin` is a VC++ tool. Unfortunately Windows isn't distributed with a tool that inspects PE/COFF binaries.